# flip a coin infinitely with a periodic sequence

Tags: probability

If I have a coin that has a probability of Tails P(T)=q (biased toward tails) and keep tossing it forever, what is the probability of the event that I start seeing a repeating pattern ?

So I'm told the answer is 0, but I was hoping the community to clarify the reasons for it being 0.  Following is my thought process:

Let's say the period=1.  Then we need to prove P(THTHTHTHTHTHTH.......)=0

Let's say the period=2.  Then we need to prove P(HTHHTHHTHHTHHTH......)=0

Let's say the period=3.  Then we need to prove P(HTTHHTTHHTTHHTTH.....)=0

.....

..... this goes on forever for increasing periods.

So the period could be any number and we could have any pattern (the above patterns are just examples).

Let B = the event there is some sequence that has a pattern during the coin flipping into eternity.

We need to prove that P(B)=0.

In order to prove P(B)=0 (i.e. there exists no pattern that could ever emerge from tossing a coin forever) we need to partition B into smaller countable sets.

$P(B) = P((B \cap period=1) + P((B \cap period=2) + P((B \cap period=3)....$

By partitioning it like above we know that B can be broken up into something that is countable.  So since we know it is countable we can apply the following formula:

$P(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty B_i) = \sum_{k=b}^c{P(B_i)}$

Now each of the individual (partitioned) probabilities are 0 and therefore the sum adds up to 0.

What's unclear to me is how the partition was created.  Could somebody give a better explanation of how partitions are created and exactly how the probability of each partition is 0?

Comment: For any given period, there are only finitely many sequences with this period. Thus the periodic sequences form a countable set. This is all you need to know.

Comment: In order to prove that P(B)=0 you first need to define what P(B) _is_.  This means that you need to understand the notion of a measure on the probability space; once you have that, this becomes relatively straightforward.  An easier way to see this (or say it) is to note that each periodic flip pattern corresponds (1:1) to the binary expansion of a rational number in [0..1], whereas arbitrary sequences correspond to the binary expansions of reals in [0,1] (with a probability distribution that's based on q, but this can be finessed away).  Then this just says that the rationals have measure 0.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki - Could you give me an example of a binary expansion of a rational number vs binary expansion of reals?

Comment: @user1068636 As a for-instance, the binary expansion of $\frac37$ is $.011011011011011\ldots$, which can be put into one-to-one correspondence to the sequence HTTHTTHTTHTT..., etc.  The binary expansion of a number is eventually periodic (including the terminating case, where the eventual  period is 1) if and only if the number is rational; this is a classical result, and easy to prove.

Comment: @ChristianRemling - so you are saying for period=1, period=2, period=3,..and so on each have a finite number of sequences that repeat.  So it forms a set like : S =  { {Seq_1_1, Seq_1_2}, {Seq_2_1,Seq_2_2,Seq_2_3, Seq_2_4},...}  where Seq_i_j represents the "j"th sequence for the "i"th period. And you are saying set S is countable.

Comment: (To go one way, note that if the number is rational then in the classic 'long division' algorithm the partial remainders eventually repeat and then the series of quotient digits also repeat; to go the other, note that a periodic sequence of digits corresponds to a geometric series that can be summed to a rational result)

Comment: There are two period $1$ sequences, namely $HHH\ldots$ and $TTT\ldots$, four period $2$ sequences (where I'm counting my period $1$ sequences again, but that's fine) etc.

Comment: @Christian Remling: I would count $HTTHTHHHHHHHHHH\ldots$ as a period $1$ sequence

Comment: @Henry: I would call this eventually periodic, and of course the same argument works for these as well.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I would mark somebody's answer as correct if they posted an answer.  All of the above comments were very helpful.  By the way - do any of you guys know of a textbook that has similar problems as the one I described above? Problems that we need to determine if they something is countable or not.